# How can i update the column to a particular value in a cassandra table?

Tags: cassandra, cql, cassandra-2.0, cassandra-3.0, cql3

Hi I am having a cassandra table. my table has around 200 records in it . later i have altered the table to add a new column named budget which is of type boolean . I want to set the default value to be true for that column . what should be the cql looks like.

I am trying the following command but it didnt work

```
cqlsh:Openmind> update mep_primecastaccount set budget = true ;
SyntaxException: line 1:46 mismatched input ';' expecting K_WHERE
```

appreciate any help
thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Any operation that would require a cluster wide read before write is not supported (as it wont work in the scale that Cassandra is designed for). You must provide a partition and clustering key for an update statement. If theres only 200 records a quick python script or can do this for you. Do a `SELECT * FROM mep_primecastaccount` and iterate through ResultSet. For each row issue an update. If you have a lot more records you might wanna use spark or hadoop but for a small table like that a quick script can do it.

Answer (score 0):

Chris's answer is correct - there is no efficient or reliable way to modify a column value for each and every row in the database. But for a 200-row table that doesn't change in parallel, it's actually very easy to do.

But there's another way that can work also on a table of billions of rows:

You can handle the notion of a "default value" in your client code. Pre-existing codes will not have a value for "budget" at all: It won't be neither true, nor false, but rather it will be outright missing (a.k.a. "null"). You client code may, when it reads a row with a missing "budget" value, replace it by some default value of its choice - e.g., "true".